# The particular digit in the number of total

Tags: c++, int, digit

When you have such a definition:

```
int variable = 253243243;
```

Can I somehow refer for example to the third digit in this number? Something along the lines of vector or array? I need this to compare whether a certain digit in the number corresponds to a different figure given by the user. Is it even possible?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the question. Why the downvotes?

Comment: Karmic balance restored :)

Comment: Third digit from the left or from the right?  A couple of the answers below are counting from the right.  It's a bit trickier doing it from the left unless you just print the value to a string and index the string.

Comment: @Ali: Because it doesn't show research effort (which is part of the description on the downvote button).  It doesn't mention attempted solutions and what went wrong.  These are not optional features of questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract digits with a combination of `%` and `/` operations.

Alternatively, you can print the number to a `string` using `stringstream` and extract digits as characters from the string:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << variable;
std::string s = ss.str();
unsigned char first = s[0] - '0'; // this is the first digit (from left)
unsigned char second = s[1] - '0'; // this is the second digit (from left)
```

Alternatively, if you are lucky enough to use a C++11 conforming compiler, you can use [std::string::to_string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) function instead of `std::stringstream`.

Comment: I'd point out that the number will be unintuitively reversed when using this method. `ss.c_str()[0]` is the far left digit.

Comment: or just use [`std::to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/)

Comment: @Casey How do you know that OP meant 'least significant digit' by saying 'first digit'? Another intuition is 'the first digit you would write writing this number...'

Comment: @Blastfurnace that's right, I improved the example in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`variable % 1000 / 100` takes the third digit

Answer (score 3):

A generic formula is:

```
(number % pow(base, the_digit_you_want)) / pow(base, the_digit_you_want - 1)
```

You also have to take care to trunc/cast to int.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++11, you can also do it this way:

```
int variable = 253243243;
std::string s = std::to_string(variable);
int x = 3; // the position you want
char digit = s[s.size() - 1 - x]; // x position from the right
char otherDigit = s[x - 1]; // x position from the left (1-based)
```

The modulo-division pattern will be more efficient (in terms of CPU time and memory).

Comment: I think the line showing extraction of an `x`th character from left is not quite right, I mean it is extracting `x`th character from right. Similar problem with the next line - I think you just need to swap 'left' with 'right' :-)

Comment: @piokuc Oops.  Fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

This question led me to create a small "STLish" container for digits... More for fun than for real life usage. But nevertheless, here it is:

```
#ifndef __DIGITS_H__
# define __DIGITS_H__

# include <type_traits>
# include <cmath>
# include <cassert>
# include <iterator>
# include <sstream>
# include <algorithm>

namespace digits
{   
    // Default base type traits, infer base size from the number of character
    template <char... Chars>
    struct base_char_traits
    {
        // Mandatory for the digits container, maybe someone want to make
        // another traits with  wchar ?
        typedef char value_type;

        // Size of the base, computed from the number of characters passed
        static constexpr size_t size = sizeof...(Chars);

        // Array of characters use to print the output
        static constexpr value_type characters[sizeof...(Chars)]  = { Chars... };
    };

    // **sigh**
    // Instantiation of the array of character; otherwise there will be a link
    // error
    template <char... Chars>
    constexpr typename base_char_traits<Chars...>::value_type base_char_traits<Chars...>::characters[sizeof...(Chars)];

    // All your bases are belong to us !
    struct base2_traits : public base_char_traits<'0', '1'> { };
    struct base8_traits : public base_char_traits<'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'> { };
    struct base10_traits : public base_char_traits<'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'> { };
    struct base12_traits : public base_char_traits<'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b'> { };
    struct base16_traits : public base_char_traits<'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'> { };


    // The digit container with the base traits and the type as template
    // parameter.
    //     
    // It is a read only container that allows you to iterate on the digit in 
    // the base given as template parameter.
    template <typename BaseTraits, typename T = unsigned long>
    class digits
    {
    public:

        // Assert that T fullfil our criteria
        static_assert(std::is_integral<T>(), "T must be integral");
        static_assert(std::is_unsigned<T>(), "T must be unsigned");        

        // Value type is defined by the base traits to allow the use of more
        // complicated digit type (here we only handle char)
        typedef typename BaseTraits::value_type value_type;

        // Reference type is defined to be the same as value type because this is an immutable container
        typedef typename BaseTraits::value_type reference;

        // The size type of the container, i.e. the type that will be used to
        // express a digit position
        typedef size_t size_type;

        // Iterator class allowing one to walk through the number's digit from 
        // the lowest to the highest 
        class iterator 
        { 
        public:

            // Type used to return iterator substraction result
            typedef size_t difference_type;

            // type used by algorithms (e.g. find)
            typedef typename digits::reference reference;

            // type used by algorithms (e.g. find)
            typedef typename digits::reference pointer;

            // type returned by operator*
            typedef typename digits::value_type value_type;

            // Iterator category, here we can randomly walk in the digit
            typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;

            // Mandatory default constructor, initialize to an invalid iterator
            iterator()
            {
                _current_digit = 0;
                _digits = nullptr;
            }

            // Build an iterator other a digits container starting at digit
            iterator(const digits* digits, size_type digit)
            {
                _current_digit = digit;
                _digits = digits;
            }

            iterator(const iterator& it) :
            iterator(it._digits, it._current_digit)
            {

            }

            // Move using swap idiom
            iterator(iterator&& it) :
            iterator()
            {
                swap(*this, it);
            }

            ~iterator()
            {
                _digits = nullptr;
            }

            // assignment iterator using swap idiom
            iterator& operator=(iterator it)
            {
                swap(*this, it);
                return *this;
            }

            // Comparison operators
            bool operator==(const iterator& it) const
            {
                assert(_digits == it._digits);
                return (_current_digit == it._current_digit);
            }

            bool operator!=(const iterator& it) const
            {
                return !(operator==(it));
            }

            bool operator<(const iterator& it) const
            {
                assert(_digits == it._digits);
                return (_current_digit < it._current_digit);
            }

            bool operator>(const iterator& it) const
            {
                assert(_digits == it._digits);
                return (_current_digit > it._current_digit);
            }

            bool operator<=(const iterator& it) const
            {
                assert(_digits == it._digits);
                return (_current_digit <= it._current_digit);
            }

            bool operator>=(const iterator& it) const
            {
                assert(_digits == it._digits);
                return (_current_digit >= it._current_digit);
            }

            // Moving the iterator
            iterator& operator++()
            {
                ++_current_digit;
                return *this;
            }

            iterator operator++(int)
            {
                iterator it(*this);
                operator++();
                return it;
            }

            iterator& operator--()
            {
                --_current_digit;
                return  *this;
            }

            iterator operator--(int)
            {
                iterator it(*this);
                operator--();
                return it;
            }

            iterator& operator+=(size_type increment)
            {
                _current_digit += increment;
                return *this;
            }

            iterator operator+(size_type increment) const
            {
                iterator it(*this);
                return (it += increment);
            }

            friend iterator operator+(size_type increment, const iterator& it)
            {
                return (it + increment);
            }

            iterator& operator-=(size_type decrement)
            {
                _current_digit -= decrement;
                return *this;
            }

            iterator operator-(size_type decrement) const
            {
                iterator it(*this);
                return (it - decrement);
            }

            difference_type operator-(const iterator& it) const
            {
                assert(_digits == it._digits);
                return (_current_digit - it._current_digit);
            }

            value_type operator*() const
            {
                assert(nullptr != _digits);

                return _digits->digit(_current_digit);
            }           

            friend void swap(iterator& first, iterator& second)
            {
                std::swap(first._digits, second._digits); 
                std::swap(first._current_digit, second._current_digit);
            }

        private:

            // The current digit we will be printing when calling operator*().
            // From 0 to (digits.size() - 1)
            size_t _current_digit;

            // The digit container we're working on.
            const digits* _digits;
        };      

        // Define the reverse iterator, that will allow to iterator from the
        // highest digit to the lowest (more printing friendly)
        typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;

        // Default constructor use 0 as a number
        digits() 
        {
            _number = 0;
        }

        // Build a container over a number given as parameter
        digits(T number) 
        {
            _number = number;
        }

        digits(const digits& copy) :
        digits(copy._number)
        {            
        }

        // Move constructor using swap idiom
        digits(digits&& move) :
        digits()
        {
            swap(*this, move);
        }

        ~digits()
        {
        }

        // Retrieve the digit character
        value_type digit(size_t digit) const
        {
            assert(digit < size());
            constexpr size_t base = BaseTraits::size;

            // @warning
            // llround is mandatory because of a double to unsigned long problem
            T modul = static_cast<T>(llround(std::pow(base, digit + 1)));
            T div =  static_cast<T>(llround(std::pow(base, digit)));
            T digit_index = (_number % modul) / div;         

            return BaseTraits::characters[digit_index];
        }

        // Assignment using swap idiom
        digits& operator=(digits assign)
        {
            swap(_number, assign._number);
        }

        // Comparison operator
        bool operator==(const digits& comp) const
        {
            return (_number == comp._number);
        }

        bool operator!=(const digits& comp) const
        {
            return !(operator==(comp));
        }       

        // Iterators creation
        iterator begin() const
        {
            return iterator(this, static_cast<size_type>(0));
        }

        iterator cbegin() const
        {
            return begin();
        }

        iterator end() const
        {
            return iterator(this, size());
        }

        iterator cend() const
        {
            return end();
        }

        reverse_iterator rbegin() const
        {
            return reverse_iterator(end());
        }

        reverse_iterator crbegin() const
        {
            return reverse_iterator(cend());
        }

        reverse_iterator rend() const
        {
            return reverse_iterator(begin());
        }

        reverse_iterator crend() const
        {
            return reverse_iterator(cbegin());
        }

        // swap function
        friend void swap(digits& first, digits& second)
        {
            std::swap(first._number, second._number);
        }

        // cast to string
        operator std::string () const
        {
            std::ostringstream stream;

            // print from high to low
            std::copy(rbegin(), rend(), 
                      std::ostream_iterator<value_type>(stream, ""));
            return stream.str();
        }

        // The number of digits of this _number
        size_type size() const
        {            
            const double log_number = std::log(_number);
            constexpr double log_base = std::log(BaseTraits::size);
            return  std::ceil(log_number / log_base);
        }

        // The maximum nulber of digits this type can have
        size_type max_size() const
        {
            constexpr double max_number = std::pow(2, sizeof(T) * 8);
            constexpr double log_max_number = std::log(max_number);
            constexpr double log_base = std::log(BaseTraits::size);
            return  log_max_number / log_base;
        }

    private:

        // The number we will iterate over the digits
        T _number;
    };
}

#endif // __DIGITS_H__
```

Basic usage would be something like:

```
digits::digits<digits::base10_traits> dig(123456);

for (auto digit: dig)
{
    std::cout << "Digit: " << digit << std::endl;
}
```

I think that most of the STD algorithm on immutable container (`for_each`, `find`, `copy`, etc.) will work with that container.

A small test here (header + test in the same file): http://ideone.com/BoMX5Q

Ok, it's pretty useless, but it was really fun to do. :)